# Getting PointerEvent instead of jQuery.Event on ng-click in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm in the middle of migrating an old codebase of AngularJS from hundreds of `<script>` tags to es modules (The only reason I mention that, is because it might give some insights into why I'm getting this odd behavior).

I found out that in the old codebase (and in every other place in StackOverflow), given an ng-click with $event, a `jQuery.Event` is being injected into the callback:

```html
<button ng-click="doX($event)">Click me</button>
```

```js
$scope.doX = ($event) => {
  console.log($event); // $event: jQuery.Event
};
```

[image: jQuery.Event]

But, in the new codebase (which I'm using Vite), I'm getting `$event: PointerEvent` instead.

What's the explanation for this? does it check a global variable declaration to decide whether to wrap the original event with a jQuery?

#### [See Playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/angularjs-forked-5orxq?file=/src/index.js:125-239)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging the source code of angular.js, I found these lines that led me to my solution

```js
function bindJQuery() {
    // ...
  
    // bind to jQuery if present;
    var jqName = jq();
    jQuery = isUndefined(jqName) ? window.jQuery :   // use jQuery (if present)
             !jqName             ? undefined     :   // use jqLite
                                   window[jqName];   // use jQuery specified by `ngJq`
  
    // Use jQuery if it exists with proper functionality, otherwise default to us.
    // AngularJS 1.2+ requires jQuery 1.7+ for on()/off() support.
    // AngularJS 1.3+ technically requires at least jQuery 2.1+ but it may work with older
    // versions. It will not work for sure with jQuery <1.7, though.
    if (jQuery && jQuery.fn.on) {
      jqLite = jQuery;
      extend(jQuery.fn, {
        scope: JQLitePrototype.scope,
        isolateScope: JQLitePrototype.isolateScope,
        controller: /** @type {?} */ (JQLitePrototype).controller,
        injector: JQLitePrototype.injector,
        inheritedData: JQLitePrototype.inheritedData
      });
    } else {
      jqLite = JQLite;
    }
  
    // ...
  }
```

Basically, angular.js is looking for jQuery in the global `window` variable. Since we're using ES modules, we can't just put `window.$ = jQuery` in the beginning of our code.

### A quick solution

Import jQuery globally in your index.html file.

### A better solution

Since I'm using [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/), I created a plugin that allows me to modify the source code of `angular.js` file. I added the following lines in the top file:

```js
import $ from "jQuery";
window.jQuery = $;
```

The way I did it while maintaining the source maps, was by using [recast](https://github.com/benjamn/recast).

#### Steps

1. Create a file called `vite-plugin-third-party-modifiers.ts`:

```js
import { PluginOption } from "vite";
import recast from "recast";

export function thirdPartyModifierPlugin(): PluginOption {
  return {
    name: "third-party-resolvers",

    transform(src, id) {
        const fileName = id.split(/[/]+/).pop().split("?")[0];

        if (fileName === "angular.js") {
            const ast = recast.parse(src);
            const b = recast.types.builders;

            // adds: window.$ = jQuery
            ast.program.body.unshift(
                b.importDeclaration(
                  [b.importDefaultSpecifier(b.identifier("jQuery"))],
                  b.literal("$")
                )
              );

            // adds: import $ from "jquery"
            ast.program.body.unshift(
                b.expressionStatement(
                  b.assignmentExpression(
                    "=",
                    b.memberExpression(b.identifier("window"), b.identifier("$")),
                    b.identifier("jquery")
                  )
                )
              );

            return recast.print(ast);
        }

        return null;
    },
  };
}
```

2. import this plugin in `vite.config.js`

```
export default defineConfig({
  // ...
  plugins: [
    thirdPartyModifierPlugin(),
  ],
  // ...
});
```